# I am facing an issue tabBar Menu and Sidebar Menu in swift

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uitabbar, sidebar

I created tab bar menu and also a sidebar menu in my application, but when i swipe my sidebar menu then my tab bar menu just disappeared, how can i fix this issue in **swift**?

Comment: TabBar and SideBar together is not a good UX. Please use either of them, unless it is deadly required for some reason.

Comment: Please share your code.

Comment: Even using both will not reproduce this issue can you please share your code.

Answer (score 2):

Which sidebar menu(if use any library) you're using didn't mention here but I've already implemented following library in several Swift apps with Tab bar and it's working very well-

https://www.appcoda.com/sidebar-menu-swift/

Comment: i am implementing your shared code, hopefully it will work.